# Do AKS and GKE can expose their logs collecting applications through APIs?

Tags: amazon-s3, google-kubernetes-engine, amazon-cloudwatch, azure-aks, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

For every cloud provider, we have different ways of looking at logs (i.e., Cloudwatch for EKS, [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/view-master-logs) for AKS etc).

It looks like I can [easily](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/S3ExportTasksConsole.html) transfer the logs from Cloudwatch to S3. Do AKS and GKE can expose their logs collecting applications through APIs? I'd like to transfer the logs from all cloud providers (EKS, AKS, GKE) to S3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On AKS, if the monitoring is activated, Microsoft will deploy a wrapper around Fluent Bit to send the logs to Log Analytics. You can then use the [Log Analytics API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/loganalytics/dataaccess/query/get) to fetch the logs. On GKE, you can do something similar with the [Cloud Logging API](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/api/tasks/exporting-logs).

Whit that said, your best bet would probably be to install [Fluentd](https://docs.fluentd.org/) or [FluentBit](https://fluentbit.io/) on all your cluster and send your logs directly to [S3](https://docs.fluentd.org/output/s3).

Comment: Could you also attach some examples where one would you FluentD / FluentBit to get the logs from K8S's control plane from master nodes (not just worker nodes) of AKS / GKE?